# Message: Call to undefined function redirect()

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am having a serious problem in using `redirect()` method.

This is my code;

```
class ictcon extends CI_controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        if(!$this->session->userdata("in")) redirect("wew");
    }
....
```

the other controller

```
<?php
class wew extends CI_controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function index(){
        $this->load->view("login");
    }
}
```

It returns

> Call to undefined function redirect()

Why would that be?

Answer (score 3):

This function belongs to the url helper. Try loading this helper in autoload file or run this before calling `redirect()`:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Comment: I did the two possible solutions but still error... "Host Not Found or connection failed"

Comment: redirect expects an url. you are redirecting to "wew". It's normal to get that error. You need to redirect to `redirect(baseurl("wew"));`.

Comment: I tried. but the error is now 'Call to undefined function baseurl()'. I also tried 'redirect(base_url()."wew");' still unlucky .. :-(

Comment: sorry I forgot the underscore. it'll be `base_url();`

Comment: does `yoursite.com/wew` exist? if it doesn't it's normal that you're getting this.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement `redirect("wew");` is correct.

Open your config file in ./app/config/config.php

Please put your site url in `base_url`

For example:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';
```

Comment: Hi RaymondM !
thanks for the reply. I tried putting the base url but does not change anything. :-(

Comment: Maybe some server config mistake? You may verify it by trying the header redirecting not using the codeigniter first.